# can't open passbook passes when served through an nginx reverse proxy

Tags: ios, nginx, passbook

My problem is that I can download passbook passes directly from my api, but with nginx as a reverse proxy in front of my api, safari can no longer open the pass.

I have a system with a ticket-service, an api and an nginx instance that operates as a reverse proxy.

I can request a ticket as a passbook pass file directly from the api through my ios simulator, but when I do the same with nginx between, ios safari returns: "Safari cannot download this file.".

I have tried to do the two requests through chrome on my laptop to check the headers and noticed that nginx adds two; `Connection: keep-alive` and `Server: nginx`.

I then tried to add those two to the api as well, just to check that safari don't complain about them and the headers then seem to be the same in chrome.

***Headers***

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Etag
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="JABJcCu42k"
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 72312
Content-Type: application/vnd.apple.pkpass
Pragma: no-cache
Server: nginx
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Thu, 09 Jul 2015 10:01:31 GMT
```

Does anyone have experience or have an idea of what the problem might be?

Thanks!
BR Fredrik

Comment: Could you share headers that you receive from server directly bypass Nginx?

Comment: Is the Content-Type header possibly getting stripped out by nginx?

Comment: The problem seemed to be that I modified the _Content-Length_ in the api and when that line was removed, everything worked like a charm.